# Fill values "down" when pivoting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm doing a PIVOT command. My row label is a date field. My columns are locations like [NY], [TX], etc. Some of the values from the source data are null, but once it's pivoted I'd like to "fill down" those nulls with the last known value in date order.

That is if column NY has a value for 1/1/2010 but null for 1/2/2010 I want to fill down the value from 1/1/2010 to 1/2/2010, and any other null dates below until another value already exists. So basically I'm filling in the null gaps with the same data for the closes date that has data for each of the columns.

An example of my pivot query I currently have is:

```
SELECT ReadingDate, [NY],[TX],[WI]
FROM 
    (SELECT NAME As 'NodeName', 
            CAST(FORMAT(readingdate, 'M/d/yyyy') as Date) As 'ReadingDate',
            SUM(myvalue) As 'Value' 
     FROM   MyTable) as SourceData 
PIVOT (SUM(Value) FOR NodeName IN ([NY],[TX],[WI])) as PivotTable 
Order BY ReadingDate
```

But I'm not sure how to do this "fill down" to fill in null values

Sample source data

```
1/1/2010, TX, 1
1/1/2010, NY, 5
1/2/2010, NY null
1/1/2010, WI, 3
1/3/2010, WI, 7
...
```

Notice how there is no WI for 1/2 or NY for 1/3 which would result in nulls in the pivot result. There is also a null record too also resulting in a null. For NY once pivoted 1/2 needs to be filled in with 5 because it's the last known value, but 1/3 also needs to be filed in with 5 once pivoted since that record didn't even exist but when pivoted it would show up as null value because it didn't exist but another location had the record.

Comment: Can you provide the basic schema for MyTable ?

Comment: NAME is varchar, readingdate is varchar, and myvalue is numeric

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  And, can you provide an example of what the source data looks like?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? With 2012 you could think about LAG(). Another approach was a tally table with all months, making sure, that each month is part of the result set and then do something mit CASE ...IS NULL

Comment: Using 2012. Will update the question with sample source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a pain in SQL Server.  ANSI supports a nice feature on `LAG()`, called `IGNORE NULL`s, but SQL Server doesn't (yet) support it.  I would start with the using conditional aggregation (personal preference):

```
select cast(readingdate as date) as readingdate,,
       sum(case when name = 'NY' then value end) as NY,
       sum(case when name = 'TX' then value end) as TX,
       sum(case when name = 'WI' then value end) as WI
from mytable
group by cast(readingdate as date);
```

So, we have to be a bit more clever.  We can assign the `NULL` values into groups based on the number of non-NULL values before them.  Fortunately, this is easy to do using a cumulative `COUNT()` function.  Then, we can get the one non-NULL value in this group by using `MAX()` (or `MIN()`):

```
with t as (
      select cast(readingdate as date) as readingdate,
             sum(case when name = 'NY' then value end) as NY,
             sum(case when name = 'TX' then value end) as TX,
             sum(case when name = 'WI' then value end) as WI,
      from mytable
      group by cast(readingdate as date)
     ),
     t2 as (
      select t.*,
             count(NY) over (order by readingdate) as NYgrp,
             count(TX) over (order by readingdate) as TXgrp,
             count(WI) over (order by readingdate) as WIgrp
      from t
     )
select readingdate,
       coalesce(NY, max(NY) over (partition by NYgrp)) as NY,
       coalesce(TX, max(TX) over (partition by TXgrp)) as TX,
       coalesce(WI, max(WI) over (partition by WIgrp)) as WI
from t2;
```

Comment: Wow, I'll have to play with that for a second to get a grasp on it :)

Comment: Would this work if there is no data for an entire month...?

Comment: @Shnugo . . . I'm not sure where that question comes from.  Months are not part of the calculation.  This will work as long as there are previous days with values.

Comment: So will need special case if first value is null?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . That is not specified in the question, but it is easy to add.  It is just a third argument on the three `coalesce()` calls.

Comment: Could you add that as it may be the case now that I look at some of the data. It may not start with data but have data after. Could you fill up in that sense?

Comment: @user441521 . . . You should ask another question with sample data and be clear about how you want to define values for `NULL` rows.  This question is quite clear and the answer could be quite different.